# Make while loop inaccessible

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, break

I'm trying to make a simple game to practice what I've been learning in class. But I'm unable to fix a `while` loop that is doing something I don't want it to do.

If `player_one_range_counter` is identical to one of the spots (`spot_1`, `spot_2`, `spot_3`, etc.) the loop should be `False` and inaccessible. The same thing should happen if `player_two_range_counter` is identical to one of the spots.

If both are identical to one or any of the spots, that means their respective loops become `False` and the game is over.  The problem is even when they're both identical to one or any of the spots the game continues. It shouldn't.

Could someone enlighten me on what I've done wrong?

```
continue_game = True
while continue_game:

    player_one_play = True
    player_two_play = True

    while player_one_play:
        print(user_1_name) 
        x = steps_to_move() # returns int from steps_to_move()
        player_one_range_counter += x # updates the range for palyer one
        user_1_turtle.fd(x) # turtle move x amount of pixels forward

        if player_one_range_counter == spot_1 or player_one_range_counter == spot_2 or player_one_range_counter == spot_3 or player_one_range_counter == spot_4 or player_one_range_counter == spot_5:
            print("\n" + user_1_name, "stepped on a mine! \n")
            player_one_play = False
        else:
            break

    while player_two_play:
        print(user_2_name)
        y = steps_to_move()
        player_two_range_counter += y
        user_2_turtle.fd(y)

        if player_two_range_counter == spot_1 or player_two_range_counter == spot_2 or player_two_range_counter == spot_3 or player_two_range_counter == spot_4 or player_two_range_counter == spot_5:
            print("\n" + user_2_name, "stepped on a mine! \n")
            player_two_play = False
        else:
            break

    if player_one_play == False and player_two_play == False:
        continue_game = False
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the primary problem is that this is *inside* the `while` loop:

```
player_one_play = True
player_two_play = True
```

when it should be *before* the `while` loop.  How I might approach your code logic:

```
spots = [spot_1, spot_2, spot_3, spot_4, spot_5]

player_one_playing = True
player_two_playing = True

while True:

    if player_one_playing:
        print(user_1_name)
        steps = steps_to_move()  # returns int from steps_to_move()
        user_1_turtle.fd(steps)  # turtle move x amount of pixels forward
        player_one_range_counter += steps  # updates the range for player one

        if player_one_range_counter in spots:
            print("\n" + user_1_name, "stepped on a mine!\n")
            player_one_playing = False

    if player_two_playing:
        print(user_2_name)
        steps = steps_to_move()
        user_2_turtle.fd(steps)
        player_two_range_counter += steps

        if player_two_range_counter in spots:
            print("\n" + user_2_name, "stepped on a mine! \n")
            player_two_playing = False

    if not (player_one_playing or player_two_playing):
        break
```

The inner `while` loops in your original code are effectively `if` statements so I have made them such in my code.